# Responsive background CSS position

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have a problem with my background on mobile phones.

I use media query and I can't make position of that background image.

Here you can see [a background image](http://stefanvblog.com/category/news/).

This is my media query code:

```
@media only screen (max-device-width : 360px) {

    .sidebar {
        display: none;
    }

    li#menu-item-631 a {
        width: 100px;
    }

    #navmenu {
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
    }

    .content {
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-top: -130px;
    }

    .contentsing {
        width: 500px;
        height: auto;
        margin-left: 20%;
        margin-right: 5%;
        margin-top: -150px;
    }
}
```

And this is my background code

```
body {
    background: url() no-repeat top center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: AntonioLight;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Is your website even responsive?

Comment: I'm really sorry but it's very unclear what it is you're actually asking..  Do you think you could provide us with more details on what the problem is, and what you're trying to achieve?  If possible, put together an example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that way people can interact with your code.

Comment: Ok I just read, you are using device width there

Comment: I'm not sure about what the question is, but the background image is perfect on any screen size, and your website is not responsive.

Comment: But it is not ok on mobile device... i try it on Samsung S4. Evrything is ok but that background image is too big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your background image to adapt to different screen sizes (priorizing the center of the image, for example), you might be looking for something like this: http://johnpatrickgiven.com/jquery/background-resize/